# Is it possible to deploy a app on multiple server with nginx, uwsgi and django whose session backend is redis?How?

Tags: django, nginx, redis, uwsgi

After days of searching, I find [nginx load banlancing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) seems to be the solution, but I am not sure.

1. Context

I have a django app `mydomain` running with uwsgi and nginx on a server A(outer ip 120.25.x.200). its `nginx.conf` and `uwsgi.ini` is [here](https://github.com/pronan/c_data_structures/blob/master/server-conf). I use redis 2.8 for a cached session:

```
# /apps/mydomain/proj/settings.py
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"
```

I use Posrgresql as database:

```
# /apps/mydomain/proj/settings.py
DATABASES = {'default': {
    'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME'    : 'muser',
    'USER'    : 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '*****',
    'HOST'    : '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT'    : '5432', 
}}
```

With `uwsgi /apps/mydomain/uwsgi.ini` and `service nginx start` the app works well on server A.

2. My guess

If I want to add two more servers B(120.25.x.201) and C(120.25.x.202) together with A to serve the app `mydomain`, could I just follow the steps:

```
# step 1:change the nginx.conf file on server A --- 
# change the server block's `location /` in http block, others remain same
http {
    upstream mydomain {
        server 120.25.x.200:80;
        server 120.25.x.201:80;
        server 120.25.x.202:80;
    }

    server {
        # ...
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  http://mydomain; 
            include     /apps/mydomain/uwsgi_params;
        }
        # ...
    }
}

# step 2:on server B and C, I make a copy of the `mydomain` app environment 
# in the same path.

# step 3:on server B and C, I change the cache and database settings 
# in /apps/mydomain/proj/settings.py like this(just replace 
# the local ip 127.0.0.1 with A's ip):

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        # ...
        "LOCATION": "redis://120.25.x.200:6379/1",
        # ...
    }
}
DATABASES = {'default': {
    # ...
    'HOST'    : '120.25.x.200',
    # ...
}}

# step 4:on server B and C,use `uwsgi /apps/mydomain/uwsgi.ini` to start the app.
# step 5:on server A, start the app with nginx and uwsgi as usual.
```

3. Question

Is my guess right? Can the redis cached session data and Postgresql database shared in serve A, B and C?

Or, is there a better solution for my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is proper solution, but think if it is necessary. Maybe your bottleneck isn't django app but database. Probably better approach will be to move database to another server, so it will have all resources available.

Comment: does you mean A B C servers share a database server?  plus, where to place redis server?

Comment: Yes, you must have one database server or some kind of replication (which is really hard to achieve). Redis can be anywhere. It is hard to say what will scale most in your app without knowing how it works and where do you have some bottlenecks.